# How to register global databinding for LocalDate in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

I'd like to use `LocalDate` as type in a `Servlet` created with `spring-mvc`.
The users should be able to provide the date in multiple valid formats `yyyyMMdd, yyyy-MM-dd, yyMMdd, yy-MM-dd`.

Therefor I'm trying to register my own converter for that class and **register it globally** for the whole application. But it is never picked up

Problem: my custom editor is never called.

```
@Bean
public CustomEditorConfigurer init() {
    CustomEditorConfigurer c = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
    c.setPropertyEditorRegistrars(new PropertyEditorRegistrar[] {
            (registry) -> registry.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new LocalDatePropertyEditor())
    });
    return c;
}

public class LocalDatePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        this.setValue(LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        return this.getValue().toString();
    }
}


@RestController
public void DateServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void test(@RequestParam LocalDate date) {

    }
}
```

When calling:
`localhost:8080/test?date=2017-07-05`

> Exception:
>   `Parse attempt failed for value [2017-07-05]`

During debug I can see the `LocalDatePropertyEditor` class is never called. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know why `PropertyEditor` does not work.
But the following solutions worked.

```
@Configuration
public class LocalDateConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.addFormatters(registry);
        registry.addFormatterForFieldType(LocalDate.class, new Formatter<LocalDate>() {
            //override parse() and print()
        });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Even I faced the problem and could not get PropertyEditor to work without initBinder():

Adding below code to each controller would work, I am using springboot v1.5:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, 
            new LocalDateEditor());
    }
```

But bit more easier solution apart from using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  as described by @membersound  is to use converters

```
@Component
public class LocalDateSerializeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(AppConstants.DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD);

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String text) {
        return LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatterForFieldType(LocalDate.class,
                new TemporalAccessorPrinter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")),
                new TemporalAccessorParser(LocalDate.class, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")));
    }
}
```