# How to receive LocalDate as parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-time, localdate

I am trying to insert a simple object into database but on my controller i am unable to send `LocalDate` parameter.

the error says `malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing` which i am quite sure this `LocalDate` parameter is causing.

**my controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/finance",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postFinance(@ModelAttribute("finance") 
        Finance finance, Model model){
       financeServices.targetActivate(finance);
       model.addAttribute("targetSetStatus",true);
        return "finance/finance";
}
```

**Finance Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Finance {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate targetDate;
    private Double targetAmount;
    private LocalDate createdDate;

      //getter setters //

}
```

EDIT:-
I am trying to insert from form so my form looks like:-

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="productForm" 
th:action="@{/finance}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <div th:if="${targetSetStatus}">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <p>New Target Has Been Set</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" 
                for="targetAmount">Target Amount:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="number" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Targeted Amount" 
                               name="targetAmount" id="targetAmount">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" 
            for="targetDate">Target Date:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="date" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Targeted Date"
                                name="targetDate" id="targetDate">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Set Target</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

if i replace LocalDate with `java.util.Date` it works but i want to use LocalDate it the API provided by java 8.

Comment: Base support coming in future, see [the pull request and resolution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/9930). In the meantime, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924656/how-to-register-global-databinding-for-localdate-in-spring-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

You must register a custom JsonDeserializer. Use this code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@JsonComponent
public class CustomJsonDeserializer {

    /*public static class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDate localDate, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        }
    }*/

    public static class LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

        @Override
        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            String strDate = jsonParser.getValueAsString();

            if (strDate == null || strDate.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            return LocalDate.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
    }

}
```

look this link [Custom JSON Serializers and Deserializers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-json-components)

Comment: i am using spring mvc not spring boot. so does this still work?  i wrote the above class importing spring boot dependencies but it didn't work.

Comment: This link can help you [link](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html)