# Spring Data Rest returning Dates in millisecond format

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have a entity with Dates **(java.util.Date)** fields defined this way:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaInicio;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaFin;
```

I have RestController to get the entities, the problem is the format i'm getting is Milliseconds for dates:

```
{"id":1,"tipoPlanId":320,"precio":155000.0,
"cantidad":6,"fechaInicio":1546300800000,"fechaFin":1551312000000}
```

I dont know why is not returning the default date format for Spring data rest **"2019-02-10T06:15:16.000+0000"**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Spring 2.x and for me `Date` is returned in the proper format.
However, you can also enforce it by:

- Adding `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false` in your properties file
- Or by annotating your member variable with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

So, in your case class will be like:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date fechaInicio;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date fechaFin;
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, I strongly recommend to use java.time.LocalDateTime/java.time.LocalDate instead of java.util.Date (time zones handling is a nightmare when using java.util.Date and you could end up inserting wrong date/time in your database), formatting the date using @JsonFormat may fix the format issue only but you may face data discrepancy while processing the date/timestamp value.

If you use SpringBoot, there is formatter registered in Spring Context used to handle LocalDate/LocalDateTime and you can use this data type without doing any change to your configuration.

Now, if you don't use Spring Boot you may have to register the LocalDate/LocalDateTime formatter in your configuration (see this post [How to register global databinding for LocalDate in spring mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924656/how-to-register-global-databinding-for-localdate-in-spring-mvc), **please notice that you must register LocalDateTime type for timestamps**)

Date/Timestamp processing is not a trivial thing in Rest/Spring, but believe me if you implement LocalDate or LocalDateTime you will not break your head trying to find out what is wrong with some dates/timestamps that are inserted with wrong values in the database.

Sample Classes

DTO

```
public class Cookie {
    private long id;
    private LocalDateTime expirationDate;

    //Getters/setters and other stuff

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chocolateCookies")
public class ChocolateCookieApi extends CookieApi<ChocolateCookie> {

    @GetMapping("/{cookieId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cookie> findCookie(@PathVariable long cookieId) {
        final Cookie cookie = new Cookie();
        cookie.setId(cookieId);
        cookie.setExpirationDate(LocalDateTime.now().plusWeeks(4));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(cookie, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //Other cookie stuff

}
```

End point testing

[image]

Code available in GitHub https://github.com/karl-codes/cookie-monster

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

My only idea is to convert it to a human readable date like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String humanReadableDate = sdf.format(fechaFin);
```